# How to setup a server-side text editor on Openshift for NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

First of all: a bit of back story (because maybe this is not the best solution I could find). I have a long 6 hour-long course on web technologies this weekend and we will do a bit of NodeJS coding. We were told to bring laptops, but mine broke down a few years ago and all I have is a Nexus 7 tablet and I want to use it to write code (with a USB keyboard). I realize there are a few Android text editors with ssh / ftp support, but I would rather do everything in a browser, for simplicity and better control.

My solution was to use a nodejs file manager with code editing capabilities to write and execute scripts on the same server. I found [Scripted](https://github.com/scripted-editor/scripted), which looks lovely, but after putting it in the root of my cloud app (via git), I keep getting the error 503 Service Unavailable. Trying to install it via ssh using `npm install -g scripted` will return `npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/scripted'` (probably because Openshift will not give me write access to referenced configuration files). The server is running nodejs v0.10.25, so could it be a problem that Scripted has only been tested on version up to 0.8.16 ?

I'm a beginner with nodejs and any help is much appreciated. Cheers !

Comment: This is not meant to be a full blown answer but a comment around the EACCESS error. Did you try sudo npm install scripted -g ? It's just permissions issue since you are doing a global install. I'll try to test scripted out and let you know when I get a chance. In the meantime, tmux and vim could work out.

Comment: Maybe try just using Cloud 9 IDE?

Comment: Openshift does not allow sudo :(. Cloud 9 is an amazing product, but it's not mobile friendly - it's rather slow, and the keyboard will often cover the most part of the IDE. The most viable solution I found was CodeAnywhere, whose services are much like Cloud 9, but also offer an Android app (which has its fair share of bugs).